# Disadvantages and advantages in changing Index mode to Manual update

Tags: extensions, indexing, importexport

we bought magento extension for uploading the products through excel sheet.

we are uploading Products using csv file.

But when we are uploading the csv file , its taking more time to upload.

At the time of uploading, site will load very slowly.

so we are planning to change Index mode to Manual update.

If we set " Manual Update" , is we have to Reindex again once we upload all products through the excel sheet.

Is there any other disadvantage from changing Index mode to Manual update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's all. You have to do a manual reindex after any change in the product / category data, like import or save in backend.